# android how to control shutter time

Tags: android

I develop a camera app ,I want to control camera's shutter time ,is that possible to realize?and what I want to realize final is prolong the exposure function,thank for your answer.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481746/any-chances-to-reduce-shutter-time-with-android-ndk-camera-access

Comment: @AndroidLearner I have checked it before I ask ,but i'm not sure it's the answer

Comment: @AndroidLearner so the answer is that I can't prolong the exposure time,right?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access the camera's shutter speed but the Camera API lets you [set the exposure compensation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29). If you want to take a burst of exposure-bracketed shots, then lock the auto-exposure and then set the exposure compensation to a value between the min and the max. Check [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) for the complete list of accessible parameters.